# Is Cantor set $F_{\sigma}$ set or $G_{\delta}$ set?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Is Cantor set an $F_{\sigma}$ set? or a $G_{\delta}$ set?

There are similar questions on stackexchange, which consider a subset of Cantor set. But, I don't find the question posted above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Cantor set is closed, hence an $F_\sigma$ as well as a $G_\delta$.

To see that any closed set is a $G_\delta$, simply note that

$$
A = \bigcap_n A^{1/n},
$$

where $A^\delta := \{x \mid \mathrm{dist}(x, A) < \delta\}$.

Comment: Oh! I didn't look at this simple argument. Thanks for the answer.